# Large http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirror.constant.com%2f file left after installing cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I just installed Cygwin with no problems (I hope!) Now there is a directory

http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirror.constant.com%2f

sitting in my download folder taking about 18.5 Gigabyte of my disk space. Can I get rid of it? And if yes, why doesn't cygwin installation leaves it there?

Answer (score 2):

#### Can I get rid of it? And if yes, why doesn't cygwin installation leaves it there?

Yes, you can remove it.

The installation leaves it there as it is a copy of the installation files and you chose to do a local install.

Presumably you also chose to install everything:

> Q: How do I install everything?
>
> A: You do not want to do this! This will install an enormous number of
>   packages that you will never use, including debuginfo and source for
>   every package.
>
> If you really must do this, clicking on the "Default" label next to
>   the "All" category to change it to "Install" will mark every Cygwin
>   package for installation. Be advised that this will download and
>   install tens of gigabytes of files to your computer.

Source [Cygwin Installation](https://cygwin.com/install.html)